# openvpn VPN server certificate retrieval

Tags: openssl, certificate, openvpn

I have a linux machine (the client) that connects to a remote server via an openvpn VPN tunnel. (Mutual authentication is in place)
I need as part of a pentest, to retrieve the certificate from the VPN server sent to the client when establishing the VPN tunnel.

When I type the command
`openvpn --config client.conf`
, in the logs I can see the server certificate but not its details.
I tried to scan the packets sent over the network with wireshark and tcpdump but the certificate still doesn't appear.

I noticed in the folder /etc/openvpn/client/ the presence of the key "ta.key" which seems to block attempts. The documentation indicates "SSL/TLS handshake initiations from unauthorized machines (while such handshakes would ultimately fail to authenticate, tls-auth can cut them off at a much earlier point)."

Answer (score 0):

```
openssl s_client -connect <server>:<port> –showcerts
```

Comment: I tried this command but the presence of the static key "ta.key" seems to block the request. (https://openvpn.net/community-resources/hardening-openvpn-security/)